# Too many indices for array error - scipy.intergate.solve_ivp(method = Radau) gives error

Tags: scipy, ode

I am supposed to solve a ODE as follows:

```
def dHdt(t, H):
  if H>H_p(t) and data2_sleep(t)>0:
    return -0.323*24
  elif H>H_p(t) and data2_sleep(t)==0:
    return 0.116*24
  elif H<=H_m(t) and data2_sleep(t)>0:
    return -0.278*24
  elif H<=H_m(t) and data2_sleep(t)==0:
    return 0.150*24
  elif H<=H_p(t) and  H>H_m(t) and data2_sleep(t) > 0:
    return -0.274*24
  elif H<=H_p(t) and  H>H_m(t) and data2_sleep(t) == 0:
    return 0.096*24
```

where H_*p, H_m, data2_*sleep are objects that are results of interpolation using scipy.interp1d .

For the solver, I used solve_ivp but methods as 'RK45' or 'LSODA' were not giving good results (by which I mean , I have a approximate solution at hand and comparing with it , results differ a lot. Moreover, another solver odeint can do much better job except it also is unstable I think) and wanted to use stiff solvers as Radau and BDF but when running below

```
H_new = solve_ivp(dHdt, t_span = [0, 50], y0 = [H0], method = 'Radau', t_eval = t_span)
```

I get the following error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-6595d5c7194d> in <module>
----> 1 H_new = solve_ivp(dHdt, t_span = [0, 50], y0 = [H0], method = 'Radau', t_eval = t_span)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/common.py in _dense_num_jac(fun, t, y, f, h, factor, y_scale)
    325     h_vecs = np.diag(h)
    326     f_new = fun(t, y[:, None] + h_vecs)
--> 327     diff = f_new - f[:, None]
    328     max_ind = np.argmax(np.abs(diff), axis=0)
    329     r = np.arange(n)

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed
```

indeed H0 is a single number but in the dHdt there is no indexing and indexing issue is raised by solver itself. (Also, only those stiff solvers make this error but if you change method to RK45 or etc it works).

What do you think is the reason for this error?

Comment: Full error message please!

Comment: You've dug into the source code more than I have.  `f[...,None]` would run if `f` is indeed 0d, but I don't know what this `f` is - or how it relates to your inputs.

Comment: The solver might call the ODE function outside the integration interval. Are the interpolation functions able to handle this? You might catch this with a default return value in the ODE function. // Or in other words, use a debugger to find the inputs to `dHdt` at the point of error and explore the return value of it. I suspect it is `None`, leading to an zero-dimensional numpy array in the wrapper.

Comment: The return value for `fun`, i.e. first positional arg to `solve_ivp`, supposedly must be `array_like` and not just a float.  From https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html "fun must return array_like with shape (n,)".   Note that `H` should also be array_like, yet you are presumably treating it like a float. Without the full code, or at least a representative look at what the other functions do, it is hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out for Radau and some solvers output must be in brackets,[]. For other solvers it is okay not to.

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).